# Gradle or Android Studio is not using the correct dependency version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm use `SavedStateRegistryOwner` class, but something wrong.

```kotlin
class MyLifecycleOwner : SavedStateRegistryOwner { ... }
```

In the end I found out that it was a dependency version problem.

I check `SavedStateRegistryOwner` source code, then I jumped to `androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.2.1@arr` package.

```kotlin
interface SavedStateRegistryOwner : LifecycleOwner { ... }
```

then I check `LifecycleOwner` source code, I jumped to `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0` package, which means something wrongs. The correct version should be `2.6.1`

Then I run gradle command to check dependency version:

```
gradle <module>:dependencyInsight --configuration debugCompileClasspath --dependency androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common
```

and then get the following output:

```
androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.6.1
  Variant apiElements:
    | Attribute Name                                  | Provided     | Requested  |
    |-------------------------------------------------|--------------|------------|
    | org.gradle.category                             | library      |            |
    | org.gradle.dependency.bundling                  | external     |            |
    | org.gradle.jvm.version                          | 8            |            |
    | org.gradle.libraryelements                      | jar          |            |
    | org.gradle.status                               | release      |            |
    | org.gradle.jvm.environment                      | standard-jvm | android    |
    | org.gradle.usage                                | java-api     | java-api   |
    | org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type              | jvm          | androidJvm |
    | com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr |              | 7.4.2      |
    | com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr  |              | debug      |
   Selection reasons:
      - By constraint: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.6.1
      - By ancestor
```

I think this should indicate that my module depends on the correct version `2.6.1`, but I don't know why it is actually using `2.0.0`.

how to solve this problem?

Comment: This doesn't sound like Gradle is having any problem at all - it seems like this is more of a Studio issue, right?

Comment: @ianhanniballake It's hard for me to tell where the problem is, I copied the dependencies of this module into the new project, but the new project Android Studio is using the correct version.